# How to keep a group of lines in a text file if one of the groups lines contains a specific string using powershell?

Tags: powershell

To be more specific, the situation is as follows:

We use a Perl script to get data and that data is output to a text file in the format.

```
Method: ...
Path: ...
Url: ...

Method: ...
Path: ...
Url: ...
```

(And so on up to however many are generated.)

I would like to keep one of the blocks (Method, Path and Url) if a matching (pre-specified) string is found in "Path" for example.

My understanding is that I would need to somehow group the blocks but I do not know how to do this. Is there a way do so and then keep the block if a matching string is found in one of the blocks' lines?

For example, delete block 2 above (Method, Path, Url) if the string "foo" is found in "Path". The lines are all sufficiently unique to allow this.

I have only found ways to delete or keep single lines if it matches a string, for example keep all "Path" lines if it matches string. But that deletes everything else which is not ideal.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Select-String -Context` to include strings before and after a match:

```
Select-String -Path C:\file.txt -Pattern "^Path: ((?!foo).)*$" -Context 1
```

Assuming that the input file looks like:

```
Method: GET
Path: some bar path
Url: http://google.com

Method: POST
Path: some foo path
Url: http://bing.com
```

Output will look like:

```
  C:\file.txt:1:Method: GET
> C:\file.txt:2:Path: some bar path
  C:\file.txt:3:Url: http://google.com
```

To get just the lines themselves, you'll need to grab the appropriate context properties from the output:

```
Select-String -Path C:\file.txt -Pattern "^Path: ((?!foo).)*$" -Context 1 |ForEach-Object {
    $_.Context.PreContext,$_.Line,$_.Context.PostContext |Out-File C:\output.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: If the output file should not be UTF-16, Output-File should use -Encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mathias. The method works. I did more research based on your answer and I used "-SimpleMatch" instead as my Regex is terrible.

However, without "-Append"  it lists only the first match. Is there a reason?

Comment: @JamesPatrick When you leave out the `-Append` switch, `Out-File` will overwrite the file every time. Either use the `-Append` switch or use `Add-Content` instead of `Out-File`